# .htaccess redirect 404 page not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am having some issues with my `.htaccess` file. For some reason, some domains work while others give me 404 page not found error.

So currently I am entering my domains like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/domain/google.com
```

Which should redirect to:

```
http://mywebsite.com/whois.php?domain=google.com
```

Having `whois.php?domain=google.com` with any domain doesn't give me a 404 error but on some domains I get 404 error with `domain/google.com`. So I narrowed it down to my `.htaccess` being at fault.

Here is how my `.htaccess` looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?domain/([^/d]+)/?$ /whois.php?domain=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have tried several different things including adding:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(domain)/(.*)$  /whois.php?domain=$2 [L,QSA]
```

So basically whatever comes after domain you pass it as a param to your script.

Explanation of Lines 2-4

- Line 2 - if file is found, execute it, don't pass to whois script (example: http://example.com/somefile.php will get executed correctly)
- Line 3 - if such a directory exist execute (http://example.com/somedirectory)
- Line 4 - everything else is passed to whois.php script, so no such directory or file (example: http://example.com/domain/google.com -> there is no such file or directory)

Comment: That works... can you explain lines from 2 to 4? So I know more about .htaccess

Comment: If it works, please accept my answer. Explaining in edit in sec